# De Morgan's Laws in Haskell via the Curry-Howard Correspondence

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, demorgans-law, curry-howard

I implemented three of the four De Morgan's Laws in Haskell:

```hs
notAandNotB :: (a -> c, b -> c) -> Either a b -> c
notAandNotB (f, g) (Left x)  = f x
notAandNotB (f, g) (Right y) = g y

notAorB :: (Either a b -> c) -> (a -> c, b -> c)
notAorB f = (f . Left, f . Right)

notAorNotB :: Either (a -> c) (b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c
notAorNotB (Left f)  (x, y) = f x
notAorNotB (Right g) (x, y) = g y
```

However, I don't suppose that it's possible to implement the last law (which has two inhabitants):

```hs
notAandBLeft  :: ((a, b) -> c) -> Either (a -> c) (b -> c)
notAandBLeft  f = Left  (\a -> f (a, ?))

notAandBRight :: ((a, b) -> c) -> Either (a -> c) (b -> c)
notAandBRight f = Right (\b -> f (?, b))
```

The way I see it, there are two possible solutions:

1. Use `undefined` in place of `?`. This is not a good solution because it's cheating.
2. Either use monomorphic types or bounded polymorphic types to encode a default value.

   ```hs
   notAandBLeft  :: Monoid b => ((a, b) -> c) -> Either (a -> c) (b -> c)
   notAandBLeft  f = Left  (\a -> f (a, mempty))

   notAandBRight :: Monoid a => ((a, b) -> c) -> Either (a -> c) (b -> c)
   notAandBRight f = Right (\b -> f (mempty, b))
   ```

   This is not a good solution because it's a weaker law than De Morgan's law.

We know that De Morgan's laws are correct but am I correct in assuming that the last law can't be encoded in Haskell? What does this say about the Curry-Howard Isomorphism? It's not really an isomorphism if every proof can't be converted into an equivalent computer program, right?

Comment: I'd tend to suspect that you're applying the isomorphism incorrectly.

Comment: I don't think I'm applying the isomorphism incorrectly. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Note that these formulas are purely propositional (no quantifiers around). Since propositional intuitionistic logic is decidable, you can solve these problems using a theorem prover (e.g. Djinn). If the prover fails, then it surely is a non intuitionistic tautology.

Comment: Think about what this "law" could possibly mean, computationally. It says, "whenever a conjunction is false, you can *find out* which conjunct is false". E.g., we know `(a, a -> c) -> c`, so de Morgan tells us we can decide any proposition `a`, solve the Halting Problem, you name it. Even if Haskell's polymorphism were not parametric, that would be a rather big ask. But with parametric polymorphism, this "law" has to decide an arbitrary proposition without knowing what the proposition is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing that stands out to me is that you don't seem to be using the definition or any property of negation anywhere.

After reading the [Haskell Wikibooks article on the CHI](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/The_Curry%E2%80%93Howard_isomorphism#Negation) here is a proof assuming that you have a law of the excluded middle as a theorem:

```
exc_middle :: Either a (a -> Void)
```

and the proof of the `notAandB` de Morgan law would go like:

```
notAandB' :: Either a (a -> Void) -> ((a,b) -> Void) -> Either (a -> Void) (b -> Void)
notAandB' (Right notA) _ = Left notA
notAandB' (Left a)     f = Right (\b -> f (a,b))

notAandB = notAandB' exc_middle
```

Comment: The only problem is that you can't construct a proof for the law of the excluded middle. You can only construct a proof for the law of the excluded middle not being false. I guess this can't be done in constructive type theory.

Comment: It's nice to discover that there's a wikibook article about myself. And on top of that, it's about one of the coolest topics I've ever found! ;-P

Answer (score 6):

The fourth law is [not intuitionistic](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/120209/4712). You'll need the axiom of excluded middle:

```
lem :: Either a (a -> c)
```

or Pierce's law:

```
pierce :: ((a -> c) -> c) -> a
```

to prove it.