# Haskell dot (.) operator in de Morgan's law implementation

Tags: haskell, demorgans-law, dot-operator

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37016673/de-morgans-laws-in-haskell-via-the-curry-howard-correspondence), the author has written an implementation of de Morgan's laws in Haskell. I understand the implementations of `notAandnotB`, and `notAornotB`, but I'm struggling to understand the implementation of `notAorB` which is:

```
notAorB :: (Either a b -> c) -> (a -> c, b -> c)
notAorB f = (f . Left, f . Right)
```

Could someone explain how the `(f . Left, f . Right)` part works? I've seen the `.` operator used before, but with three arguments, not two.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that the definition of the `.` operator is `(f . g) x = f (g x)`, *i.e.* `f . g = \x -> f (g x)` (syntactically, it is a *binary* operator, it is just that Haskell’s syntax sugar permits the latter definition to be restated as the former). So, the definition you have can be rephrased as

```haskell
notAorB f = ((\x -> f (Left x)), (\y -> f (Right y)))
```

(this can be done mechanically by [Lambdabot](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lambdabot) on [#haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/IRC_channel), tell him to `@unpl ‹expr›`), or more verbosely

```haskell
notAorB f = (lt, rt)
  where lt x = f (Left x)
        rt y = f (Right y)
```

---

As always, try writing down the types. If `(.) :: ∀ s t u. (t -> u) -> (s -> t) -> s -> u`, `f :: Either a b -> c`, `Left :: ∀ p q. p -> Either p q`, then `f . Left` or `(.) f Left :: a -> c`, *etc.*